# Pyenv can't find system python (3.8) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ansible, pyenv

In case anyone is trying to reset to Python "system" in Ubuntu 20.04, you may run into this error:

```
Pyenv can't find system python (3.8) on Ubuntu 20.04
```

I discovered this when I tried to install Ansible on Ubuntu 20.04 (this was after I had installed pyenv):

```
$ ansible-playbook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 34, in <module>
    from ansible import context
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'
```

I tried to set default Python back to "system" and saw the following:

```
$ pyenv global system
pyenv: system version not found in PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could find to fix this was by running:

```
$ sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

This fixed the problem and I could run ansible-playbook (and other ansible commands) successfully afterwards. I hope this is helpful to someone who runs into a similar problem.